# Why am I getting this "Only variables should be passed by reference" error with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting this error:-

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

... and I don't have any idea what's going on; the error occurred in this code:

```
public function prepare_items() {
    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    $this->items = $this->flagged_message();

    usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
    $this->items = $this->flagged_message();        

}
```

This line is the error:

```
 usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
```

The `flagged_message()` function is:

```
public function flagged_message(){
    global $wpdb;
    $improper_contents = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT comment_id FROM pw_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'flag_this_message' AND meta_value = '%d'", $this->flagged_id) );
    $flagged = [];
    if($improper_contents){
        foreach ($improper_contents as $improper_content_arr) {

        $comment_id = (int)$improper_content_arr->comment_id;
        $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $comment_content = $comment->comment_content;
        $comment_author = $comment->comment_author;
        $comment_post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
        $comment_date = $comment->comment_date;
        $comment_who = $comment->user_id;

        $flagged[] = array(
            "ID"                =>  $comment_id,
            "username"          =>  $comment_author,
            "flagged_message"   =>  $comment_content,
            "date"              =>  $comment_date,
        );

        }

    }
    return $flagged;
}
```

I don't understand why the error is being raised, can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Result returned by function **is not** a variable.

Comment: `usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );` change it to `$message_data = $this->flagged_message();usort( $message_data, array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );`

Comment: Hi guys thank you for givin me an idea about the error i try all of your suggested solution but none of them work, but the important thing you guys explain me the error message. My solution used was on the function flagged_message() before the return $flagged, i put this code usort( $flagged, array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) ); thanks and it works, by the way i forgot to mention that im using wordpress cms but i know i doesn't matter. thank you again

Answer (score 5):

**[usort](http://php.net/usort)**

```
bool usort ( array &$array , callable $value_compare_func )
```

Expects an array by reference to sort it, and you are sending it a `function` as first parameter. That's it.

I know that your function returns an array but you need to store it in a variable so its reference can be passed to `usort`. A function's return value is not known outside its scope to be referenced in another function without saving this value in a variable first. If `usort` didn't expect that parameter by reference then your code would have been fine.

Any call by value function will accept that just fine.

**Note**

It's quite possible that you have the parameters in wrong order mistakenly. Because your second parameter seems to be an array which is wrong there too. First one should be an `array` and second one a `callable` and you have them reversed. But even then that's not really how to call `usort`

Your call should look something like this

```
$messages=$this->flagged_message();
usort($messages , 'usort_reorder');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `usort()` function reference, the first parameter will be an array, but you are sending a function, this cause the error, so change like below:-

```
usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
```

Change it to:-

```
$message_data = $this->flagged_message(); // assign function return value to a variable
usort( $message_data,'usort_reorder'); // pass the variable to the function as first parameter. check the change in second parameter too
```

Or

```
$message_data = $this->flagged_message(); // assign function return value to a variable
usort( $message_data,array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) ); // pass the variable to the function as first parameter.
```

Note:- for more detail check manual:- http://php.net/usort

**I change the second parameter in first example, because the second parameter must be a `valid callback function`, and you passed an array (i feel that is not correct). That’s why i added second example too.Try both and which one works for you, use that one**

Comment: Sorry which type of `usort` call is that? You sure that second parameter is fine?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, let me add comment related this.

Answer (score 1):

try change

```
usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
```

to

```
usort( $this->flagged_message(), array( $this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
```

hope his help.